# Recover Data from a Restore from a Backup?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, system-restore

Recently, the computer was not working, and thus the computer had to be restored to a backup from a month ago. The restore worked perfectly, except for one problem: since I had done all my work on it, I essentially lost about a month's work of game save data, video editing, photos, phone backups, scripts, Photoshop work...

And out of a 3 month computer? Basically 2/3rds of my useful data was restored to how it was before.

So is there any way to restore this data? Because that lost month's worth of data probably contains some of the most important data ever written to the disk.

Also, the other disk (a 3TB disk split into 3 partitions) was fine. Just most of the data was on C:, especially because of the fact that the SSD drive behind C: is much faster than the slow HDD that is the 3TB drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### .. is there any way to restore this data?

Possibly. The first thing to do is to stop using the drive immediately.

When data is 'erased', it is usually simply marked as 'overwritable' by the drive. As such, the data stays there until a write request is made to the drive. The drive looks for empty space or space that is flagged as 'overwritable', and at this point, the original data is lost. All the while you are using the drive, the system will be reading and writing temporary data which could quite possibly overwrite the data you want.

You will want another computer to either hook the drive up to, or create yourself a live boot drive to use on that computer so you're not actually writing to it.

You can then run a drive level recovery utility across the drive, which will hopefully pick up any data that hasn't already been overwritten, such as `Recuva`, `EaseUS` or `R-Studio`, to name a few.

---

I will mention, there is absolutely no guarantees with data recovery. As you've restored an entire partition in place, and likely used the computer in the mean time, there is a very good chance this data is now irretrievable or corrupted. I'd recommend turning off the machine, finding another computer you can connect the system drive to and attempting a recovery (Always recover to a different drive than you are trying to recover from, as you might accidentally overwrite the data you wanted).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to hook up the SSD to another PC. Since the recover, though, others have been using the computer, though, so I doubt I'll be able to recover it.